# Update elements in a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Lets say I gave a JSONObject

```
{
 "person":{"name":"Sam", "surname":"ngonma"},
 "car":{"make":"toyota", "model":"yaris"}
 }
```

How do I update some of the values in the JSONObject?

Like below :

```
String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("person").getString("name");
name = "Sammie";
```

Comment: is this specifically an android JSON thing? Because I have tried every answer to this question and get compile errors.

Answer (score 132):

Use the put method: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject person =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("person");
person.put("name", "Sammie");
```

Comment: For what it's worth, also works with `person.element("name", "Sammie")`

Comment: To convert it back to a string, you can use the `JSONObject.toString` method.

Answer (score 38):

Remove key and then add again the modified key, value pair as shown below :

```
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    js.put("name", "rai");

    js.remove("name");
    js.put("name", "abc");
```

I haven't used your example; but conceptually its same.

Answer (score 6):

Hello I can suggest you universal method. use recursion.

```
    public static JSONObject function(JSONObject obj, String keyMain,String valueMain, String newValue) throws Exception {
    // We need to know keys of Jsonobject
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject()
    Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
    String key = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        key = (String) iterator.next();
        // if object is just string we change value in key
        if ((obj.optJSONArray(key)==null) && (obj.optJSONObject(key)==null)) {
            if ((key.equals(keyMain)) && (obj.get(key).toString().equals(valueMain))) {
                // put new value
                obj.put(key, newValue);
                return obj;
            }
        }

        // if it's jsonobject
        if (obj.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
            function(obj.getJSONObject(key), keyMain, valueMain, newValue);
        }

        // if it's jsonarray
        if (obj.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
            JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
                    function(jArray.getJSONObject(i), keyMain, valueMain, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

It should work. If you have questions, go ahead.. I'm ready.

Comment: @EriPro pls have a look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933616/change-only-the-specific-value-after-receving-the-specific-data-from-web-sockets?noredirect=1#comment59524970_35933616

Comment: What is valueMain?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, it is the old value which should be replaced.

Comment: but how to update particular position in json array ?@eabyshev

Comment: @Venkatesh first is set as parameter keyMain, valueMain (key,value - particular position in json) and newValue for replacing

Comment: Perfect, just what I need! Thank you!

Comment: this is pretty out of date. There are a number of compile errors to this code. What are the imports? Is this an Android thing?

Answer (score 1):

Generic way to update the any JSONObjet with new values.

```
private static void updateJsonValues(JsonObject jsonObj) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObj.entrySet()) {
        JsonElement element = entry.getValue();
        if (element.isJsonArray()) {
            parseJsonArray(element.getAsJsonArray());
        } else if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            updateJsonValues(element.getAsJsonObject());
        } else if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            jsonObj.addProperty(entry.getKey(), "<provide new value>");
        }

    }
}

private static void parseJsonArray(JsonArray asJsonArray) {
    for (int index = 0; index < asJsonArray.size(); index++) {
        JsonElement element = asJsonArray.get(index);
        if (element.isJsonArray()) {
            parseJsonArray(element.getAsJsonArray());
        } else if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            updateJsonValues(element.getAsJsonObject());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Manohar Thummanapelly ,  This works perfectly fine for me, except in one case, where i have JSONArray, consisting only of strings. "match_departments": [
      "L T C",
      "M I C U"
    ] . How do i update such values.? Current logic dosent update these values.

Comment: can you provide imports or say what librariy you use? For example when I try to use this it says that there is no JsonElement, there is only JsonValue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JSONObject updateJson(JSONObject obj, String keyString, String newValue) throws Exception {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            // get the keys of json object
            Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
            String key = null;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                key = (String) iterator.next();
                // if the key is a string, then update the value
                if ((obj.optJSONArray(key) == null) && (obj.optJSONObject(key) == null)) {
                    if ((key.equals(keyString))) {
                        // put new value
                        obj.put(key, newValue);
                        return obj;
                    }
                }

                // if it's jsonobject
                if (obj.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
                    updateJson(obj.getJSONObject(key), keyString, newValue);
                }

                // if it's jsonarray
                if (obj.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
                    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        updateJson(jArray.getJSONObject(i), keyString, newValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive way to update value in depth in Kotlin

Example: `setJsonValue("obj1/obj2/keyToUpdate", "new value")`

```
fun setJsonValue(path: String, value: Any?) {
    setJsonValueRec(
        path = path.split("/"),
        index = 0,
        obj = jsonObj,
        value = value
    )
}

private fun setJsonValueRec(path: List<String>, index: Int, obj: JSONObject, value: Any?): JSONObject {
    return obj.put(
        path[index],
        when (index) {
            path.lastIndex -> value

            else -> setJsonValueRec(
                path = path,
                index = index + 1,
                obj = obj.getJSONObject(path[index]),
                value = value
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject person =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("person");
person.addProperty("name", "Sammie");
```

Use `addProperty()` with overloads. If the property exists, will update the value. If it does not, will add it as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonDataString = "{\n" +
                "  \"Name\": \"Hello World\",\n" +
                "  \"Description\": \"sent\",\n" +
                "  \"Roles\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"Profile\": \"rolec\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"Profile\": \"rolec\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"Profile\": \"rolec\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        DocumentContext json = JsonPath.parse(jsonDataString);
        String jsonPath  = "$.Name";
        String newValue = "SYED";
        DocumentContext finaljson = json.set(jsonPath, newValue);
        System.out.println(finaljson.jsonString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject objectJson = new JSONObject(gson().toJson(verbaDetalhe));
        objectJson.put("Verba", verbaEditada);
```

My solution was edited via put the value of the key field.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own Method which replaces a JSON value (using **org.json.JSONObject**) with a particular value.

```
public static String replaceJSONValueAtPath(String jsonString, String[] pathToValue, Object value) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(new JSONTokener(jsonString));

    JSONObject current = obj;
    // Traverse the JSON tree along the path specified
    for (int i = 0; i < pathToValue.length - 1; i++) {
        current = current.getJSONObject(pathToValue[i]);
    }

    // Replace the value at the specified path
    current.put(pathToValue[pathToValue.length - 1], value);
    return obj.toString();
}
```

Here is the test :

```
@Test
public void test() throws JSONException {
    String stringIn = "{'a': {'b' : {'c': 'oldValue'} }}";
    String stringOut = TestUtils.replaceJSONValueAtPath(stringIn, new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}, "newValue");
    String sTest = "{\"a\":{\"b\":{\"c\":\"newValue\"}}}";
    Assertions.assertEquals(sTest, stringOut);
}
```