# Change only the specific value after receving the specific data from web sockets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sockets

Below I'm showing a specific part of a long JSON structure

```
var user = {
    map: {
        width: 785,
        height: 791
    },
    image: {
        name: "image.png",
        size: {width:32}
    },
    properties:[{
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Jones",
    }]
};
```

Now if I'm updating any value in the above JSON structure say firstName is changed from "Bob" to "Angel" how can I efficiently replace the firstName so that it will be reflected in the DOM as I'm using web sockets..
Since the JSON is huge I will be using **ng-repeat** to bind the data.
Currently I'm  reloading the entire data to see the change in the DOM which I don't need to do..

From the web socket I will be getting the updated name and the primary key if there is any associated with that particular JSON

Comment: if the same json you getting from we socket is being used for binding to view then changes in the json will reflect on view automatically

Comment: I'm gettting only a part of the JSON,ie.,the updated value

Comment: You need to update that value in the json model which is binded to view.

Comment: So I need to loop through and identify the JSON model and update?

Comment: I guess you are converting your json you get from web socket to view model thats the place you have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you update your JSON structure (actually your JavaScript object) from within an AngularJS handler function, any changes to the data are reflected to the rendered view immediately after handler functions have completed.