# Replace the JSON object after updating using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, replace

This is a follow up quesstion for [JSON replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933616/change-only-the-specific-value-after-receving-the-specific-data-from-web-sockets?noredirect=1#comment59524970_35933616)
 where I was not able to get a proper response. Hence I'm posting this question with a better example.

```
var beforeReplacement=[
    {
        "Name": "app1",
        "id": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "test1",
                "name": "test grp45",
                "desc": "this is a test group"
            },
            {
                "id": "test2",
                "name": "test group 2",
                "desc": "this is another test group"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "app2",
        "id": "2",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "test3",
                "name": "test group 4",
                "desc": "this is a test group"
            },
            {
                "id": "test4",
                "name": "test group 4",
                "desc": "this is another test group"
            }
        ]
    }
]


changed object:   
 [
        {
            "Name": "app2",
            "id": "2",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "test3",
                    "name": "changed test group 4",
                    "desc": "this is a test group"
                }

            ]
        }
    ]





 var afterReplacement=[
        {
            "Name": "app1",
            "id": "1",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "test1",
                    "name": "test grp45",
                    "desc": "this is a test group"
                },
                {
                    "id": "test2",
                    "name": "test group 2",
                    "desc": "this is another test group"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "app2",
            "id": "2",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "test3",
                    "name": "changed test group 4",
                    "desc": "this is a test group"
                },
                {
                    "id": "test4",
                    "name": "test group 4",
                    "desc": "this is another test group"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have changed the name in **var beforeReplacement** and have mentioned the modified object that I will be receiving after the changes. How can I efficiently replace this changed object in the **beforeReplacement** so that the resultant object will be like **var afterReplacement**

Comment: if you are changing the id of the test, how can you relate to which test you have changed?

Comment: @gurvinder372 updated the id,thanks

Comment: The question does not specify where the changed object comes from and isn't specific enough. You may want (especially if you've got JS on server side) to use some JSON diff library (e.g. [node-rus-diff](https://github.com/mirek/node-rus-diff)) to calculate and apply diff to existing object. A lot of NPM libraries are platform-agnostic and can be built for browser with Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: the changed object comes from the web socket

Comment: The Name field of your "changed object" is "my app2", but the Name field of your "afterReplacement" object is "app2".  Is that intentional?

Comment: yes,,that was the change that I made and need to update the same in afterReplacement,only the id remains the same

Comment: The problem is that it's very unclear what you want from your example.  If you want your "before" to be changed to include this "changed object" (assumption: The 2nd object in the array is supposed to change), why does your "after" example not show any changes?

Comment: @Tibrogargan please check now

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you want to be able to update the name field of an existing test group.  Do you want to be able to update the "Name" field?  (These are apps?).  Do you want to be able to update other fields of the group array?  Since the "changed" object has only one element in the group array and the "after" object has two elements in the group array the assumption would be that you can't delete elements from the group array.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var afterReplacement = beforeReplacement.map(function (af) {
    for(var i in changed) {
        if (changed[i].id != af.id) continue; 

        af = changed[i];
        break;
    }
    return af;
});
```

Comment: forEach is going to get quite inefficient for large arrays.

Comment: You've got the same issue with for.  change that to { af = ch; break; }

Comment: Converted to for-in :)

Comment: Now it'll stop after the 1st element every time, you need to keep the {}

Comment: what if a new item has been added or deleted in the changed object.How that can be reflected in afterReplacement array

Comment: Perhaps you should ask it in a different question :)