# How to replace value in json file

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file i.e `test.json`.

```
{
  "Added": {
    "type": "K",
    "newmem": {
      "IDNew": {
        "id": "777709",
        "type": "LOP"
      },
      "birthDate": "2000-12-09"
    },
    "code": "",
    "newest": {
      "curlNew": "",
      "addedForNew": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the following code :

```
File file = new File("test.json");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

JSONObject data =  (JSONObject) parser.parse(
   new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()
));//path to the JSON file.
System.out.println(data.toString());

JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject();
jObject.put("id","12345678");
System.out.println(jObject);
```

Result getting :-

```
{
  "Added": {
    "type": "K",
    "newmem": {
      "IDNew": {
        "id": "777709",
        "type": "LOP"
      },
      "birthDate": "2000-12-09"
    },
    "code": "",
    "newest": {
      "curlNew": "",
      "addedForNew": ""
    }
  }
}{
"id":"12345678"
}
```

Value  `id`: "777709" is not getting updating to `id`:"12345678" but it's adding at last. Please help me to and tell me how to replace the `id` value.

Comment: You need to write that json object again to the file.

Comment: You're not modifying the original object. You just created a new empty one (`jOjbect`), added an element to it and printed. You need to modify `data` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update elements in a JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159610/update-elements-in-a-jsonobject)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Could you please help how to achieve that ? I am very new to java and also not getting any good reference on Net.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this with simple json library([library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm)) . I am separately printed all object for understanding. AS you declare Id object inside two more object, so firstly you have to get this object then get your desire object  IDNew. Then put new id value in id field.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Main {

    private static final String filePath = "E:\\project-test\\scloud\\test\\src\\main\\resources\\test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // read the json file
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

            System.out.println(jsonObject);


            JSONObject addedObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Added");
            System.out.println("Added is: " + addedObj);

            JSONObject newmemObject =(JSONObject) addedObj.get("newmem");
            System.out.println("newmemObject is: " + newmemObject);

            JSONObject idNewObj =(JSONObject) newmemObject.get("IDNew");
            System.out.println("IdNewObj is: " + idNewObj);

            long id =Long.valueOf((String) idNewObj.get("id"));
            System.out.println(id);


            idNewObj.put("id",809809809);

            System.out.println(jsonObject);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Or for simplicity you can use this

```
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);

    JSONObject idObj = (
       (JSONObject) (
             (JSONObject) (
                (JSONObject)
                   jsonObject.get("Added")
             ).get("newmem")
       ).get("IDNew")
    );

    idObj.put("id", 98009809);
    System.out.println("After ID value updated : "+jsonObject);
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked :)
I can see the printed json values in console . How can i write the same value in same test.json file ?

Comment: try this :  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test");
            byte[] strToBytes = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
            outputStream.write(strToBytes);

Answer (score 6):

You can update a nested element in a `JSONObject` using the simple-json java lib as follows:

```
JSONObject added = (JSONObject) data.get("Added");
JSONObject newmem = (JSONObject) added.get("newmem");
JSONObject idNew = (JSONObject) newmem.get("IDNew");
idNew.put("id","12345678");
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: I tried the same and its adding a new value at last

Comment: get("").put("","") ;
get method do not return any put method for me.

Comment: Have imported 

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

Comment: have you surrounded it with try catch?

Comment: @KaranMer Yes  I have commented with Try and Catch

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to use getJSONObject instead of get

Comment: I cant see any getJSONObject method with data

Comment: i just realised that you are using simplejson, try the updated version

Answer (score 2):

One more solution using different library [json-path](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/):

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

    @Test
    public void exampleToReplaceSingleElement_jsonTakenFromFile() throws IOException {
        String expectedId = "12345678";
        String expectedJson = "{\n" +
                "  \"Added\": {\n" +
                "    \"type\": \"K\",\n" +
                "    \"newmem\": {\n" +
                "      \"IDNew\": {\n" +
                "        \"id\": \"12345678\",\n" +
                "        \"type\": \"LOP\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"birthDate\": \"2000-12-09\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    \"code\": \"\",\n" +
                "    \"newest\": {\n" +
                "      \"curlNew\": \"\",\n" +
                "      \"addedForNew\": \"\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        Configuration configuration = Configuration
                .builder()
                .options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS)
                .build();
        File json = new File("src/test/resources/test.json");
        System.out.println(json.getAbsolutePath());
        DocumentContext parsed = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(json);

        parsed.set("$.Added.newmem.IDNew.id", expectedId);
        String actual = parsed.jsonString();

        log.info("After ID value updated: {}", actual);
        assertThat(actual).isEqualToIgnoringWhitespace(expectedJson);
    }
```

Examples also accessible on get [test exampleToReplaceSingleElement()](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/elementary-java-lessons/blob/master/json-examples/json-path-examples/json-path-starring-values/src/test/java/org/vl/example/StarringServiceTest.java#exampleToReplaceSingleElement()) or [test exampleToReplaceSingleElement_jsonTakenFromFile()](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/elementary-java-lessons/blob/master/json-examples/json-path-examples/json-path-starring-values/src/test/java/org/vl/example/StarringServiceTest.java#exampleToReplaceSingleElement_jsonTakenFromFile()).