# How to update multiple fields in Json payload from cucumber data table

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, pojo, jackson-databind

I have a complex Json which acts like a input to a webservice. I have created necessary POJO classes for it and I am using Jackson object mapper in my code.

**Original Json:**

```
{
    "accNum": "Dummy_Account",
    "customerData": {
        "customerName": "Dummy_Name",
        "customerAddress": "Dummy_Address"
        
    },
    "accountData": {
        "cashAccountRef": "Dummy",
        "acntCrncy": "EUR",
        "foreignCurrencyAccounts": [
            {
                "foreignCurrency": "USD",
                "foreignCrncyAcntRef": "Reference"
                
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

**Cucumber Feature File**

```
Given Prepare Input request for below data
      | requestbody.accNum                                                           | 12345        |
      | requestbody.customerData.customerName                                        | New Name     |
      | requestBody.accountData.acntCrncy                                            | INR          |
      | requestBody.accountData.foreignCurrencyAccounts[0].foreignCrncyAcntRef       | New_Reference|
```

**Final Json to be passed as input**

```
{
    "accNum": "12345",
    "customerData": {
        "customerName": "New Name",
        "customerAddress": "Dummy_Address"
        
    },
    "accountData": {
        "cashAccountRef": "Dummy",
        "acntCrncy": "EUR",
        "foreignCurrencyAccounts": [
            {
                "foreignCurrency": "EUR",
                "foreignCrncyAcntRef": "New_Reference"
                
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I am using Lombok for Pojo generation.

And building the pojo like -

```
File file = new File("C:\\User\\Project\\customerRequest.json");
var requestBody = objectMapper.readValue(file, ModifyCustomerRequest.class);
```

Below line works fine to update the existing payload -

```
requestBody.accountData.acntCrncy="INR";
```

Do you know how can I update multiple fields in the payload? Something like below where I want to set the values in my POJO. In my step definition I have read cucumber datatable as map -

```
Map<String, String> data = table.asMap(String.class, String.class); 
data.forEach((k,v) -> k=v );
```

This doesn't give any error but values are not set. Need some help how can datatable in cucumber or code in step definition can be manipulated to achieve the objective.

Any pointers are helpful.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to your problem statement, parse the update json.

[Update elements in a JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159610/update-elements-in-a-jsonobject)